# Regex.Replace HTML string in empty string

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to replace a string like

```
<p><strong>@001@</strong></p>
```

or

```
<p><strong>@002@</strong></p>
```

or

```
<p><strong>@010@</strong></p>
```

or any other number from 1-to 10 in empty string.

i've tried this

```
Regex.Replace(HTML, @"[<p><a-z>@0-9@</a-z></p>]", "");
```

But it remove all the html tags from the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
Regex.Replace(HTML, @"<p><(\w+\b[^<>]*)>@0(?:0[1-9]|10)@</\1></p>", "");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jS0iI1/3)

Comment: THANKS A ALOT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :) but how can i do if  i want any number betweed 1-99 ? like @024@ to replace ?